# How do you break a large java application into components?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, service, components

I am writing a java web application using spring, hibernate and mysql. The applications is getting larger so I want to break it into smaller parts e.g. smaller projects, components or which ever way possible. For example I have login and image uploading functionality, I don't want both of these to be in a single code base or project. I want to be able to use these separately almost like separate services independent of each other. Is there a way of doing this e.g. convert the image uploading functionality into a jar and then reference this jar in the actual project? How are the Enterprise projects split?

Hope it make makes sense and please advice if I am going the right direction as it is my first project? It would be nice if someone can point me to a mini example or recommend reading.

thanks in advance

Comment: Small tip, always follow Single Responsibility Principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 1):

Try with [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage). If you are using Spring, then **declarative services** and possibly **blueprint** container in OSGi specs are what you need to leverage what you have done until now.

Try reading *OSGi in Action* by Richard S. Hall, Karl Pauls, Stuart McCulloch, and David Savage to get an insight in this technology.

OSGi is a modularazied approach for java software development that enforces loosely coupled services creation. Quoting from the OSGi alliance website:

> OSGi technology is a set of specifications that defines a dynamic component system for Java. These specifications reduce software complexity by providing a modular architecture for large-scale distributed systems as well as small, embedded applications.

Hibernate supports OSGi as it can be seen [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/ch06.html). As for the OSGi implementation, I would recommend [Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/), but many other valid OSGi implementations exist. Since your project is a web application, you could check also **[Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/)**

> Virgo from EclipseRT is a completely module-based Java application server that is designed to run enterprise Java applications and Spring-powered applications with a high degree of flexibility and reliability

and in particular,

> supports vanilla WAR files, with all their dependencies in WEB-INF/lib, and Web Application Bundles, that import their dependencies via OSGi manifest metadata, via the reference implementation of the OSGi Web  Container specification, based on embedded Apache Tomcat and configured using the standard Tomcat server.xml

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using maven modules and maven dependency management capability. I created a separate maven project and kept adding maven modules as needed e.g. created a module for image uploading, one module for common libraries and so on.
Each of these modules are then packaged to jar files. I then import each one of these jar files using maven dependency to my main web project.

It seems to have worked great so far. Hope this is helpful for someone else, too.